# UIView auto resize when transitioning subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to provide rotation support, however when transitioning between two UIViews, the autoResizingMask property appear to be ignored.

Here is a video illustrating the problem:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWtO7J6YNxA

I currently have each UIView (parent and subviews) set to:

```
uiView.autoresizingMask =  (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight );
```

Also, the parent view has:

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Comment: Are you actually setting the `autoresizingMask` programmatically?  Is this view (`uiView`) created dynamically ... is that why?  I try really hard to setup things like this in Xcode's graphical designer. You can use the graphical tool to set autoresizing mask settings, and the little animation shows you how the view will resize.  Also, I rarely set autoresizingMask as you've done.  If it's flexible width and/or height, usually I also have it pinned to left/right/bottom/top with something like `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`.  I'm not sure that's right for you ... just brainstorming.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you return from your Web View (Google page) the two views you mention above are being displayed in PORTRAIT mode but the device is in LANDSCAPE.  If so you could just store the two views frame coordinates (x,y,width and height) before you transition to the UIWebView page and restore them when you transition back.  Of course you would need to check on the return if the device is in Landscape or Portrait mode.

If you saved the Frame coordinates in PORTRAIT mode and you return to the screen from your UIWebView and the device is in PORTRAIT mode then just restore them with

```
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(savedValueOfX, 
                               savedValueOfY,
                           savedValueOfWidth,
                         savedValueOfHeight);
```

If the device is now in LANDSCAPE mode then restore them like this...

```
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(savedValueOfX, 
                               savedValueOfY,
                           savedValueOfHeight,
                           savedValueOfWidth);
```